# how to install opencv and cmake

Tags: c++, opencv

I wish to use opencv for my project(c++) since it has lot of functionality so i tried to install opencv but i couldn#t undestand the things which had been mentioned in their user guide. according to their instruction, i tried to install Cmake but i couldn't. so how to use --prefix= option to specify a custom installation directory for CMake.
according to their instruction i should do following steps;
1. run the bootstrap script from within the CMake source directory or any other build directory of your choice. 
2. Once this has finished successfully, run make and make install.
So basically it's the same as you may be used to from autotools-based projects:

$ ./bootstrap; make; make install

but i don't know how to do this. how to run bootstrap script and where? please need helps...thanks

Comment: Please add a link to the guide you are following. It seems you are trying to build CMake from source, which shouldn't be necessary. If you are in Ubuntu, just type: sudo apt-get install cmake

Comment: Can you specify the platform you are using?

Comment: the liks which i used ; http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/ and http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide. i downlaoded cmake and opencv but don't know how to install it. i am using windows and my c++ complier is dev. please explain me all steps,how to do this? thanks

Comment: i couldn't solve this yet. please anyone help me thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you are planning on using Xcode to develop:

1. Download Xcode
2. Download and install mport: https://www.macports.org/install.php
3. Download OpenCV and move it to your desired directory
4. Once you moved OpenCV to a directory you’re happy with, cd into this directory and create a folder called ‘build’ with the mkdir command.
5. Cd into this new folder and run cmake -G “Unix Makefiles”  This command will start installing what OpenCV needs to run.
6. Once it’s done, run “make -j8” in your Terminal and ‘sudo make install’.

Everything should now be installed. If you check inside your build > lib folder, you should see all the frameworks that have been installed.

7. Open Xcode and create a new project by clicking on File > New > Project.
8. Go to OSX > Application and select ‘Command Line Tool’.
9. In the next window, make sure the language selected is C++ and enter the project name you’d like. For example ‘OpenCV Tutorial’.

Your project window will then open, select the project file (the file at the top of your project), and follow these steps:

a. At the top, select Build Settings and search for Search Paths
b. Change the Always Search User Paths to true.
c. Change the Header Search Paths to usr/local/include.
d. Change Library Search Paths to usr/local/lib.
e .In the search field, remove your previous search and scroll down until you find the Linking section.
f. Double click on Other Linker Flags, click on the + button and add:

`-lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videostab`

All of the previous steps will allow Xcode to know where to look for when you import a library in your code.

Finally, go to your Xcode preferences, select Locations Tab, click Advanced and change the location button from Unique to Legacy.

You should be good to go now!

If you're okay running your applications from the terminal, follow this:

1. Download Cmake gui.
2. Download and unzip OpenCV somewhere.
3. Create two new folders inside of the openCV directory, one called staticlibs and the other sharedlibs.
4. Build the staticlibs like so:
   Open CMake.
   Click Browse Source and navigate to your openCV folder.
   Click Browse Build and navigate to your StaticLib Folder.
   Click the configure button. You will be asked how you would like to generate the files. Choose Unix-Makefile from the Drop Down menu and Click OK. CMake will perform some tests and return a set of red boxes appear in the CMake Window.

You will need to uncheck and add to the following options.

Uncheck `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`
Uncheck `BUILD_TESTS`
Add an SDK path to `CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT`, it will look something like this “/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk”.
Add x86_64 to `CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES`, this tells it to compile against the current system
Uncheck `WITH_1394`
Uncheck `WITH_FFMPEG`
Click Configure again, then Click Generate.

4. When the application has finished generating, Open Terminal and type the following commands to install the static libs on your computer.

`- cd <path/to/your/opencv/staticlibs/folder/>
- make (This will take awhile)
- sudo make install`

5. Build shared libraries the same way with some minor changes as following:
   Open CMake.
   Click Browse Source and navigate to your openCV folder.
   Click Browse Build and navigate to your SharedLib Folder.
   Click the configure button. You will be asked how you would like to generate the files. Choose Unix-Makefile from the Drop Down menu and Click OK. CMake will perform some tests and return a set of red boxes appear in the CMake Window.
   You will need to uncheck and add to the following options.

Check BUILD_SHARED_LIBS
Uncheck `BUILD_TESTS`
Add an SDK path to `CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT`, it will look something like this “/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk”.
Add x86_64 to `CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES`, this tells it to compile against the current system
Uncheck `WITH_1394`
Uncheck `WITH_FFMPEG`
Click Configure again, then Click Generate.

Once it's done running enter the following in the terminal:

`- cd <path/to/your/opencv/SharedLibs/folder/>
- make (This will take awhile)
- sudo make install`

You're done! Now to make an application do the following:

Step 1:

Create a new folder somewhere on the computer.
Inside the folder, create a CMakeLists.txt file then create a FileName.cpp file.

Step 2:

Write code. Save your file.

Step 3:
Open the CMakeLists.txt file then add the following text.

`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
    project( BlurImage )
    find_package( OpenCV )
    include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
    add_executable( FileName FileName.cpp )
    target_link_libraries( FileName ${OpenCV_LIBS} )`

Step 4: 
Open Terminal and navigate to your applications directory.

`- cd <path/to/application/folder>
    - /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake .
    - make`

To run type `Then type ./FileName` in the terminal.

Source:
http://blogs.wcode.org/2014/10/howto-install-build-and-use-opencv-macosx-10-10/

Comment: I think OP is using Windows not OSX.

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion? @MarkSetchell

Comment: The comment that starts... *"The liks that I used..."*